# Run application insights query from powershell module

Tags: powershell, azure-functions, azure-cli

With the AZ Cli I can run the following to query application insight instances:

`az monitor app-insights query`

There doesn't appear to be a direct equivalent in the azure powershell module. I've seen suggestions that you should use the REST API for application insights, but that requires an API key.

I do not have an API key for each of my (many) application insights' and do not want to have to create and store them so I can query application insights - the reason for not being able to use the Az Cli in my script is I want to run my script as a function app and the az cli isn't supported in function apps.

Is there an alternative way to query AI from powershell that I'm missing?

Answer (score 3):

At the moment, Azure PowerShell just provides the module to manage Azure application insight resource. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.applicationinsights/?view=azps-6.0.0). So if you want to query application insight with PowerShell, we need to use rest API. Besides, if you do not want to access it with API key, you can do that with AD token. For more details, please refer to [here](https://dev.applicationinsights.io/documentation/Authorization/AAD-Application-Setup)

For example

If you want to Azure AD auth to access Azure application insights API, please refer to the following steps

1. Register Azure AD application in your tenant
2. Configure API permissions
   [image]
   [image]
3. [Create a client secret for the application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-access-web-apis#add-credentials-to-your-web-application)
4. Configure  assign `contributor` to the AD application in your subscription
5. Script

```
$appKey=""
$appId=""
$resource="https://api5.applicationinsights.io"
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $appKey -AsPlainText -Force
$mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($appId, $secpasswd)

Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Tenant "hanxia.onmicrosoft.com" -Credential $mycreds
$res=Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl $resource


$headers=@{"Authorization"="Bearer "+$res.Token}
$body=@{"timespan"="P7D"; "query"="requests| summarize totalCount=sum(itemCount) by bin(timestamp, 30m)"}| ConvertTo-Json

Invoke-RestMethod 'https://api.applicationinsights.io/v1/apps/bd7cacd8-9607-4b53-b57b-995255292f36/query' -Method 'POST' -Headers $headers -Body $body -ContentType "application/json"
```

Answer (score 0):

Given you have `$appInsResourceGroupName` and `$appInsName` pointing to your Application Insights instance.

```
$component = Get-AzApplicationInsights -ResourceGroupName $appInsResourceGroupName -Name $appInsName
$apiKey = New-AzApplicationInsightsApiKey -ApplicationInsightsComponent $component -Permissions ReadTelemetry -Description "Collector"
$query = "requests | limit 5"
(Invoke-WebRequest -Method POST -Uri https://api.applicationinsights.io/v1/apps/$($component.AppId)/query -ContentType application/json -Body $('{"query":"' + $query + '"}') -Headers @{"X-Api-Key"=$apiKey.ApiKey}).Content
```

to clean up / remove unused API keys

```
Get-AzApplicationInsightsApiKey -ApplicationInsightsComponent $component | ?{$_.Description -eq "Collector"} | %{Remove-AzApplicationInsightsApiKey -ApplicationInsightsComponent $component -ApiKeyId $_.Id}
```

> if you're using any domestic clouds you need to account for that; e.g. for China you need to change the URL to `api.applicationinsights.azure.cn`